# Solve integral including Bessel function numerically in matlab

Tags: integration, matlab, bessel-functions

[image]

How can I write a code in matlab that solve this equation numerically, r & t are inputs and we can put every value.

Comment: What is the range of $\tilde{r}$ and $\tilde{t}$? Are they complex- or real-valued? Are they non-negative or strictly positive? Are there any assumptions about or relations between the variables? These things can limit the scope of solutions that need to be considered and possibly permit alternative solutions.

Comment: r and t are real and positive (t is time and r is distance). my main problem is this: I have to reach these conditions: th(1,t)=0 & th(r,0)=1 & th(inf,t)=1 because in theory I solved the equation by these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test this, but using Matlab's `integral` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)) to perform numeric quadrature, here's an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to calculate $\theta(\tilde{r},\tilde{t})$:

```
f = @(b,r,t)exp(-t.*b.^2).*(besselj(0,b.*r).*bessely(0,b)- ...
                            bessely(0,b.*r).*besselj(0,b)) ...
                         ./(b.*(besselj(0,b).^2+bessely(0,b).^2));
th = @(r,t)(-2/pi)*integral(@(b)f(b,r,t),0,Inf);
```

Just call `th(r,t)` for scalar or array values of `r` and `t`.

In older versions of Matlab you may need to use `quadgk` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quadgk.html)) instead of the newer `integral`. If performance is an issue, you may want to turn the anonymous function `f` into a regular function and only calculate `besselj(0,b)` and `bessely(0,b)` once per call. Additionally, if there are numeric issues/errors/warnings, you might try doing the math to convert to the three input argument scaled form of these Bessel functions: see [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1108455/80812) for further details.

Comment: I tried you code and it works, however using `quadgk` instead of `integral` seems to be 10x faster (I used Matlab 2014 and performed the computation 50 times). However, the results vary (difference is 1%) and both calculation yield warnings.

Comment: thak you so much for your great help

Comment: @horchler  Is there any mehod or way to get excact solution? because as you said by this code I can reach the answer by 1% or 2% error

Comment: I'm not the one who quoted the 1% error values. I have no I idea how @sonystarmap came up with those values because your question doesn't include any numeric values for $r$ and $t$. However, any numeric scheme will have some error. I don't think that there is an "exact" solution to this complicated integral, but you can use symbolic math and variable precision in Matlab to compare your results for particular values for $r$ and $t. You'd just turn the function handle `f` into a symbolic expression and replace `integral` with `int` ([documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html)).

Comment: I found this solution by these conditions: th(1,t)=0  th(r,0)=1 th(inf,t)=1 . by putting this data in the code except th(1,t)=0  other two conditoins give the vslue by warning and not excactly 0 and 1 and it's my problem.